# Automatically nest files in .csproj class libary (DependentUpon)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have a number of C# files I am generating. I would like them to automatically be nested under the matching C# file inside the Visual Studio solution explorer. For example, Foo.Generated.cs and Bar.Generated.cs would be nested under Foo.cs and Bar.cs, respectively.

If possible I'd like to be able to manage this in my Directory.Build.props file, so all the class libraries in my solution will have the same behavior.

**Versions**

- .NET Core 3.1
- Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.3)

**Failed Attempt A:**

```
<Compile Update="**\*Generated.cs">
  <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('.Generated', '.cs'))</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

**Failed Attempt B:**

```
<Compile Update="**\*Generated.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

**Failed Attempt C:**

```
<Compile Update="**\*Generated.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename).cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

The above approaches have also been tried with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicDependentFile" />
  <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicFileNesting" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Please use `Directory.Build.targets` rather than `Directory.Build.props`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If possible I'd like to be able to manage this in my
>   Directory.Build.props file, so all the class libraries in my solution
>   will have the same behavior.

**First**, I think you should use `Directory.Build.targets` rather than `Directory.Build.props`. As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order) shows, `Directory.Build.props` is imported very early in Microsoft.Common.props and Itemgroup elements are recognized after MSBuild Properties, so when you add items in `Directory.Build.props`, these elements will not be recognized by MSBuild.

**However**, `Directory.Build.targets` is imported very late which MSBuild already starts to recognize them at that time and with it, you can add any items that can be recognized in that file.

**Solution**

**1)** change your file to `Directory.Build.targets`

**2)** add these(yours) in it:

```
<Compile Update="**\*Generated.cs">
  <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('.Generated', '.cs'))</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

And it works in my side and hope it could help you.

Comment: Aaaah!  At first I thought replacing `.Generated` with `.cs` would result in `Abc.Generated.cs` being changed to `Abc.cs.cs` but then I looked up exactly what `%(Filename)` returns, and it's the original filename *without* the extension, so it's really starting with `Abc.Generated`.  Makes so much more sense now! Voting this up for also learning you can actually run code here with the `$()` syntax!

Comment: Thanks for this! Works like a charm for most things I need.  Question though... why do you have to use `[System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace(...)` instead of just `%(Filename).Replace(...)` I know you do, but I'm wondering ***why***.  Secondly, is there a way to include conditions? For instance, I want to nest `MyControl.Commands.cs` but the parent file for a `UserControl` is `MyControl.xaml` whereas for a custom control it's `MyControl.cs`. Is there any way to check if one or the other exists, then use that? (My workaround is to use `MyControl.xaml.Commands.cs` but I hate it.)